# Error in launch4j while executing the java application

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, launch4j

I created an exe file of my Java application which got created successfully. But when I try ans execute it and place some values in the form displayed , press submit button , it is showing the error:

> ```
> Executing: C:\Users\bhawna\Desktop\tto1.exe
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)    at
> ```
>
> java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)   at
>   ngo_interface.eventdetail.jButton1ActionPerformed(eventdetail.java:192)
>     at ngo_interface.eventdetail.access$300(eventdetail.java:20)    at
>   ngo_interface.eventdetail$4.actionPerformed(eventdetail.java:89)  at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

What should I do? The values are not going in the database.
                                                                                          This is the log file of launch4j:

```
CmdLine:    C:\Users\bhawna\Desktop\ttf1.exe --l4j-debug
WOW64:      yes
Check launcher:  (n/a)
64-bit search:  SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment...
Match:      SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\1.6
Match:      SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\1.6.0_32
Match:      SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\1.7
Match:      SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\1.7.0
Using 64-bit runtime.
64-bit search:  SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit...
Ignore:     SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.7
Ignore:     SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\1.7.0
Using 64-bit runtime.
Check launcher: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe (OK)
Add classpath:  mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar
Add classpath:  beansbindings-1.2.1.jar
Launcher:   C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
Launcher args:  -classpath "C:\Users\bhawna\Desktop\ttf1.exe;mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar;beansbindings-1.2.1.jar" ngo_interface.NewJFrame
Args length:    128/32768 chars
Exit code:  0
```

Comment: The database driver can not be found.  You need to specify to launch4j all the dependencies it is required to include in the class path to Java.  How to do that is another question

Comment: This is the log file of launch4j :

Answer (score 1):

just  add the mysql-connector jar file in classpath

Comment: I have added the mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar in the classpath. But its still not working. I also tried adding the classpath in the launch4j itself, but still it shows the same error. :(

Comment: are you run the jar file without make exe?

Comment: I have made the exe file using launch4j and now I am trying to execute it.

Comment: The same project is running perfect in netbeans but after i create an exe and then run it, it is showing driver error.:(

Comment: ok , try to but mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar in java lib (JDK) folder